# web.py storage object can't access value

Tags: python, web.py

I execute this sql query using web.py

```
db.query('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM episodes WHERE changed > $date LIMIT 1)', vars={'date':date})
```

the result is

```
[<Storage {'EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM episodes WHERE changed > ? LIMIT 1)': 1}>]
```

In theory I know how to turn these storage objects to lists. But every time I try I lose the value "1".
Trying [0] results in `['EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM episodes WHERE changed > ? LIMIT 1)']` without the value.
[1] is out of range.

How can I access the "1"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a list with one element, which is of type `Storage` and containts the result of your query.  A `Storage` instance is like a dictionary (type `dict`) with the extra feature of making keys also accessible as attributes.  Of course only as long as the key would be a legal attribute name which `EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM episodes WHERE changed > ? LIMIT 1)` is not. So you have to use it like an ordinary dictionary:

```
# Prints: 1
print result[0]['EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM episodes WHERE changed > ? LIMIT 1)']
```

This is a bit long so you might consider giving the result column an alias in the SQL query (`LIMIT 1` is unnecessary because it is implied in `EXISTS`):

```
db.query('SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM episodes WHERE changed > $date) has_changed_after_date', vars={'date': date})
# ...
print result[0]['has_changed_after_date']
# or
print result[0].has_changed_after_date
```